# dockerd: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos7, loopback

I'm building some CentOS VM with VMWare, with no access to internet, so I've downloaded and made local repositories, including [this one](https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/)
Then I have installed docker-engine.x86_64, and when starting the docker daemon, I get the following errors :

```
[root]# dockerd
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 993
...
...
DEBU[0001] Error retrieving the next available loopback: open /dev/loop-control: no such device
ERRO[0001] **There are no more loopback devices available.**
ERRO[0001] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: loopback attach failed
DEBU[0001] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: loopback attach failed
```

---

After manually add the loop module which control loop device with this command :

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/block/loop.ko
```

The error changes to :

```
 [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed
```

I've read that it could be because I have not enough space disk, I think it's not that, any idea?

```
[root]# df -k .
Filesystem               blocs de 1K Used      Available Used Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root    51887356 2436256   49451100   5%    /
```

Comment: I don't get why you don't have already a loop-back interface by default in the first place. Have you checked the network options of vmware ? Maybe you should set it up from the VM options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I just can add interfaces from the vmware network options, no loopback

Comment: Whats your CentOS version? Do you see loopback when you issue ifconfig? Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I can ping 127.0.0.1, and I see  lo interface with ifconfig,  for the config : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core), kernel : 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64

Comment: Creating device nodes (with `mknod`) doesn't create loopback devices.  Can you actually set up new loopback devices from the command line with `losetup`?

Comment: I really don't get it : [root]# losetup /dev/loop0 -> 
losetup: /dev/loop0: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the "There are no more loopback devices available" error, which stopped dockerd from running.

I fixed it by ensuring the storage driver was 'overlay':

```
# /usr/bin/dockerd -D --storage-driver=overlay
```

This was on Debian Jessie and docker running as a systemd service/unit.

To make it permanent, I created a systemd drop-in:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --storage-driver=overlay
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, tried your solution, and it also worked !